# Using Jenkins API in WP website - access denied

Tags: wordpress, apache, docker, jenkins

I'm trying to use the [Jenkins API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) in my WordPress website through the development of a custom plugin. About my installation, I use Docker images : WordPress, Apache, PHP, Jenkins. 
Problem is I can't access my Jenkins API from my WP site and I'm still confronted to an "access denied" error.

For my Docker installation, I am behind a corporate proxy `http://proxy:8080` and I set a local docker network
So here my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: './docker/'
      dockerfile: './httpd/Dockerfile'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - php
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      test4exoplatform_local-network:
        ipv4_address: 199.20.0.6
    volumes:
      - ./html/:/var/www/html/
    container_name: web

  db:
    build: 
      context: './docker/db/'
    ports: 
      - "3306:80"
    networks:
      test4exoplatform_local-network:
        ipv4_address: 199.20.0.9
    volumes:
       - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    container_name: db

 wordpress:
    build:
      context: './docker/wordpress/'
    environment:
      WP_PROXY_HOST: http://proxy
      WP_PROXY_PORT: 8080
    ports:
      - "3362:80"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/html/pages/wp-content
      - ./wp-config.php:/var/www/html/html/pages/wp-config.php
    networks:
      test4exoplatform_local-network:
        ipv4_address: 199.20.0.5
    container_name: wordpress

  php:
    build: 
      context: './docker/php/'
    ports:
      - "9999:80"
    networks:
      test4exoplatform_local-network:
        ipv4_address: 199.20.0.4
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    container_name: php

  jenkins:
    build:
      context: './docker/jenkins/'
    user: root
    ports:
      - "9091:8080"
    networks:
      test4exoplatform_local-network:
        ipv4_address: 199.20.0.7
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - /tmp/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home

networks:
  test4exoplatform_local-network:
    external: true
```

Inside my WordPress image, I can access the Jenkins one (via `telnet jenkins 8080`).

In jenkins, I set up as well the proxy settings.

Here my code in my WP plugin in order to access the Jenkins API:

```
$username = 'username';
$api_token = 'token';
$url = 'http://localhost:9091';
$jobName = 'test';

ch = curl_init();    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy:8080");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $api_token); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/job/' . $jobName . '/build?token=' . $api_token);
$result = executeCurl($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

It throws me this error and I really don't know how to proceed:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost:9091/job/test/build?...

    Access Denied.
```

The token and username is correct because when I enter the link (`http://localhost:9091/job/test/build?token=token`) in my browser, it does work and launch a jenkins build.

I tried as well to use the ip address I set to my jenkins docker image (`199.20.0.7`) for the link to access the API (as `199.20.0.7/job/test/build?token=token`) but I've got the error: `The requested URL could not be retrieved`

Could this be a network error?

### EDITS

OK I've made some modifications that might be helpful, I've got more info about my errors but still not understanding it..
So I removed the address ip specified in the `docker-compose.yml` file (cause I think it was blocking my requests). 
Now when I try to launch a jenkins build via my WP website, the php logs throw me :

```
php          | * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
php          | *   Trying 193.56.47.20...
php          | * Connected to proxy (193.56.47.20) port 8080 (#0)
php          | * Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
php          | > POST http://localhost:9091/job/test/build?token=token HTTP/1.1
php          | Host: localhost:9091
php          | 
php          | < HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
php          | * Server squid/3.5.20 is not blacklisted
php          | < Server: squid/3.5.20
php          | < X-Squid-Error: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
```

I don't understand, is it my proxy blocking my request for some reason?